# How to prevent accessing in storage symlink folders in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, authorization, symlink

How can I prevent storage (inside /public folder) for being public by url like **mydomain.com/storage** ? Of course I can add index.html but there are so many subfolders!

Comment: That depends on your web-server configuration. Has nothing to do with Laravel.

Comment: Laravel has storage public for that reason.    Use non public storage disk /  storage/app    and use public as storage/app/public  ,

Comment: Don't mix Web server configuration related questions with laravel. It is matter of server configuration!